# Did I vote close this question?

Tags: support, vote-to-close

[Cannot open file'*' no such file or directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/508718/cannot-open-file-no-such-file-or-directory#508718)

I don't have any recollection of voting to close as not reproducible issue.

Is it because someone use my comment as a vote close reason ?

Comment: You cast a close vote for "unclear what you're asking".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that the close reason is the majority of the type chosen by the close-voters; those voters are spelled out at the end of the notice:

> Kusalananda, jimmij, mosvy

so I would assume that those people voted as "non-reproducible" while you and glenn voted to close it with some *other* reason (which isn't listed on the notice and which was also appeared to be directly from the question, as I don't see those other two votes in the close-review queue -- just mosvy's).

Comment: What is strange though is that I do not remember casting a vote close for this question. I guess I'm a bit tired

Comment: I have an answer for that, too!  Goodnight! :)

Comment: But it's 05:00pm in France

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't control time yet. :)

Comment: Should I uncast my moderators vote for you ? :P

Comment: If you demand a time lord for a moderator, then yes :)

Answer (score 2):

another funny fact, you can't close your own question.

I mean, if you do it is  `Community♦`, see [unable to remotly query rpm](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/383398/unable-to-remotly-query-rpm)

Comment: This is wrong. You can vote to close your own question, and your vote will be listed in the same way as anybody else's. There is a separate mechanism if you ask a question, and someone else casts a duplicate vote but the question isn't closed yet, you can accept the duplicate vote. In that case, the question will become immediately marked as closed as a duplicate, and the closure will be attributed to the close voters so far (excluding you) plus Community.